# Ultraedit regular expression for parsing complex numbers

Tags: regular-expression

I have a csv file with number representations of complex numbers.

```
-0.0272780+88932190i
0.2833029-10293882i
0.1990238+22901020i
0.3009823-22389991i
```

This is a HUGE file and I would like to translate that into a complex number representation in a C header file.

```
const Ipp32fc complexes[] = {
    {-0.0272780,88932190 },
    { 0.2833029,10293882 },
    { 0.1990238,22901020 }
    { 0.3009823,22389991 },
     ... // you get the idea
```

In Find/Replace I have tried

```
[\+-]$
```

or

```
[\+-](+)$
```

to replace the inner signs with comma then I was going to perform a simple Find/Replace on `i` and strip that out.

Can't seem to get the right regex.

Comment: Why are you deleting the sign off of the imaginary parts?

Comment: You write it is a CSV file. Is this only one column of many, or does the file only contain that one column?

Comment: It is just one number each in it's own column.  That's all.  Only one column in the file.  In answer to the other question...I'm not sure that is accepted.  School me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's correct.  We may have a misunderstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` on the command line:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "const Ipp32fc complexes[] = {" } END { print "};" } { re=im=$0; sub("[+-][0-9.]*i$", "", re); sub("^-?[0-9.]*", "", im); sub("i$", "", im); printf "\t{ %s, %s },\n", re, im }' file
const Ipp32fc complexes[] = {
        { -0.0272780, +88932190 },
        { 0.2833029, -10293882 },
        { 0.1990238, +22901020 },
        { 0.3009823, -22389991 },
};
```

The `awk` command with a bit of whitespace added:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { print "const Ipp32fc complexes[] = {" }
    END   { print "};" }
    {
        re = im = $0
        sub("[+-][0-9.]*i$", "", re)
        sub("^-?[0-9.]*", "", im)
        sub("i$", "", im)
        printf "\t{ %s, %s },\n", re, im
    }' file
```

This prints out the needed C language header and footer text in the `BEGIN` and `END` blocks, while the input is parsed in the longer block.

The input from each line is assigned to both the `re` and `im` variables.  The `re` variable gets everything after the imaginary part chopped off, while the `im` variable gots the real part and the `i` removed.

Numbers are assumed to contain only digits and dots.

The data is then printed.

Comment: I'll give it a go.  Unfortunately I am on a Windows box.

Comment: @jiveturkey This is a "Unix & Linux" site.

Comment: I understand, I was going to utilize Ubuntu on Windows 10

Comment: @jiveturkey That should be ok. The only issue is if your input file is a DOS text file. In that case, run `dos2unix` on the file first.

Comment: Thanks.  Still working it.  Problem is on a different computer so writing :)